# Compiler ignores else block in AsyncTask

Tags: android, if-statement, android-asynctask

I'm implementing a login activity. Below are my set of codes inside AsyncTask. I receive JSONObjects in the form of `{"success":1, "someotherkey":someothervalue}` or `{"error":0, "error_msg":"Invalid Login"}`

```
@Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

            final String username = etUsername.getText().toString();
            String password = etPass.getText().toString();
            UserFunctions userFunctions = new UserFunctions();
            JSONObject json = userFunctions.loginUser(username, password);

            try {
                if (json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS) != null) {
                    String res = json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS);
                    if (Integer.parseInt(res) == 1) {
                        colName = json.getString(KEY_NAME);
                        // user successfully logged in
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                errorTxt.setText("");
                                Intent intent = new Intent(
                                        getApplicationContext(),
                                        AgentHome.class);
                                intent.putExtra("name", colName);
                                intent.putExtra("username", username);
                                startActivity(intent);
                            }
                        });

                    }
                }else{
                    Log.e("Login Error", "Invalid Login parameters");
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            errorTxt.setText("Invalid Username or Password");
                        }
                    });
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }
```

But when I run and enter invalid username/password, it gives the following in the logcat and does nothing else (ignores the else block in which I set the error text).

```
02-12 09:10:35.944: D/JSON(9682): {"error":0,"error_msg":"Invalid login"}
02-12 09:10:35.944: W/System.err(9682): org.json.JSONException: No value for success
02-12 09:10:35.944: W/System.err(9682):     at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:355)
02-12 09:10:35.944: W/System.err(9682):     at org.json.JSONObject.getString(JSONObject.java:515)
02-12 09:10:35.944: W/System.err(9682):     at collector.lbfinance.MainActivity$GetPassword.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:95)
02-12 09:10:35.944: W/System.err(9682):     at collector.lbfinance.MainActivity$GetPassword.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
02-12 09:10:35.944: W/System.err(9682):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
02-12 09:10:35.954: W/System.err(9682):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
02-12 09:10:35.954: W/System.err(9682):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
02-12 09:10:35.954: W/System.err(9682):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
02-12 09:10:35.954: W/System.err(9682):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
02-12 09:10:35.954: W/System.err(9682):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Edit : `String KEY_SUCCESS = "success";` `String KEY_ERROR = "error";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in log:

```
org.json.JSONException: No value for success
```

means no key exist in JSONObject with `success` name so if-else block is not executing. use [JSONObject.has()](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#has%28java.lang.String%29) for checking is `JSONObject` contains `success` key or not. do it as:

```
if (json.has(KEY_SUCCESS)) {
  //..your code here
}else{
//..your code here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It does not executes as it goes into `JSONException`. On `if (json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS) != null) {` line just inside the `try` block, the `"success"` key does not exist in case of `error`. so it gives JSONException as it is unable to find the key and parse it.